# Bad first post audit

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was presented with [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2955449) a few minutes ago and my first reaction was "This isn't a answer!". Good for me I took the time to open the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-io-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine) and see it was just an audit... but what a bad one! Without opening the question in another tab, I would have flagged as "Not an answer" and failed, since it is at best a comment to the accepted answer (how it got upvoted that much is strange).

I searched meta to know what to do in case like that and it seems, right now, that our only option is to post to get it removed. Would this audit actually be used again? I haven't find any indication that it would or not be the case.

Comment: What's the point of only ever using blatantly obvious off-topic posts for audits?

Comment: I'm not sure you would have failed the audit.  The answer already has two moderator flags on it (one of which is "Not an Answer").

Comment: Why is it bad? It is very unfitting for SE format. and the content has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @raam86: It's bad for a first post audit, because it has a score of 17 so the system probably considers it a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Good for a close audit then